# In react how do I automatically open another page?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I am new to React and finding it hard to Google (generic terms like open page!) what should be a common scenario.

My code renders a page containing a link using Linkify:

```
<Linkify properties={{target: '_blank'}}>{someText}</Linkify>
```

where `someText` contains a link to an external site. This opens in a new tab when clicked.

Is there an example of how to automatically (ie no click required) pop up this link in a new tab, after a few seconds delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple. Try setTimeout(). The `setTimeout()` method will call a function or execute a piece of code after a time delay (in millisecond). Here the called function is `window.loacation.href`, which will have the URL of the page (you wish to redirect).

```
 const redirect_Page = () => {
        let tID = setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = 
            "https://stackoverflow.com/"; //replace with your url
            window.clearTimeout(tID);// clear time out.
        }, 5000);
    }
```

I hope this will help you. All the best

Comment: Very helpful, thank you, but it doesn't 'popup'. I tried `window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');` but the timer didn't fire.

Comment: Actually, works but the browser was blocking it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<Linkify
  componentDecorator={(
    decoratedHref: string,
    decoratedText: string,
    key: number
  ) => (
    <a href={decoratedHref} key={key} target="_blank">
      {decoratedText}
    </a>
  )}
>
  {someText}
</Linkify>;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too vary late to respond but I really hope it helps others who are trying to achieve the same thing..

This fixed my problem:

```js
import ReactLinkify from "react-linkify"

<ReactLinkify componentDecorator={(decoratedHref, decoratedText, key) =>
  (
      <a target="blank" href={decoratedHref} key={key}>
          {decoratedText}
      </a>
  )}>
      {yourText}
</ReactLinkify>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is helpful and working fine:

```
<Linkify options={{target:'blank'}}> {data} </Linkify>
```